# Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be of length 1 when trying to run an Anova

Tags: r, glm, anova

I am trying to compare two glm-models with the Anova Function in R to test if they are getting better or just more complex but when I try to run the Anova I always get this error message:

```
Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be of length 1
```

My code looks like this:

```
model1 <- glm(Tempus~Typ, data=tempusB, family=binomial)

model2 <- glm(Tempus~Typ+Semantik, data=tempusB, family=binomial)

Anova(model1, model2, test="LRT")
```

I already looked in the help section of the Anova-Function and if I understand correctly it seems that with glm-models I can only use one argument? Is that the problem here? And does this mean it is not possible to use the Anova-Function in this case?

I am sorry if it's a dumb question, I am an absolute beginner with R and my professor told me to use the Anova-Function, so I tried.

Edit: Here is an example of my data.

```
dput(head(tempusB)
structure(list(Tempus = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("kT", 
"T"), class = "factor"), Typ = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("K", "M", "V"), class = "factor"), Person = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "U"), class = "factor"), 
    Numerus = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("PL", 
    "SG", "U"), class = "factor"), Aktionsart = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("dur", "perf"), class = "factor"), 
    Semantik = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Tat", 
    "Vor", "Zust"), class = "factor"),  
    Satz = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("HS", 
    "NS"), class = "factor"), Klasse = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("sch", "st", "unr"), class = "factor"), 
    Thema = structure(c(2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Arbeit", 
    "Familie", "Gem", "Leben", "Mission", "Pers", "PNG"), class = "factor"), 
    Speaker = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AC", 
    "AH", "BC", "BG", "CW", "DH", "DK", "EHA", "EHI", "EMH", 
    "EP", "ESE", "EUG", "EWH", "EWO", "HT", "JC", "JE", "JHI", 
    "JL", "MCA", "MG", "MT", "PK", "RM", "VK", "VR", "WR"), class = "factor"), 
    Interviewer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "12", "13"), class = "factor"), Sprache = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("SD", "UD", "UDSD"), class = "factor"), 
    Anzahl_P = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Geschlecht = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("m", "w"), class = "factor"), 
    Alter = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2", 
    "3"), class = "factor"), Bildung = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("C", "HS", "NE", "U"), class = "factor"), 
    Stolz = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
    "b", "U"), class = "factor"), Identität = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "U"), class = "factor"), 
    Erstsprache = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L1", 
    "L2", "U"), class = "factor"), Englisch = c(10.56, 10.56, 
    10.56, 10.56, 10.56, 10.56)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`12861` = 12861L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: Hi, without an example of your data it is likely impossible to help you. Could you edit your post and add an exemple of your data with `dput(tempusB)` or `dput(head(tempusB))` if the dataframe is very large, thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I found my own mistake and it was a dumb one, but in case anyone else stumbles over that: I have confused the anova and Anova-function with each other.
The **a**nova function (from the stats-package) works with the syntax I tried:

`anova(model1, model2, test="LRT")`

But the **A**nova function (from the car-package) only needs one model (that's why it said it only needs 1 argument), so the syntax would be:

`Anova(model1, test="LRT")`

So that's pretty much it.